# Kind of groupByKey on RDD[(K, V)] returning List[(K, RDD[V])]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, data-lineage

I would split an `RDD[(K, V)]` into buckets such as the output type would be a `List[(K, RDD[V])]`, here is my proposal. But i'm not satisfy because it rely on `keysNumber` run over the original RDD. Does it exist other way to process requiring less run over original RDD. If not, what do you think about the fact of put in cache rest before recursive call, sure it will be faster but doest Spark will minimise storage in memory because of lineage with first RDD or does it save `~keysNumber` times smallest version of original RDD. Thank you.

```scala
def kindOfGroupByKey[K : ClassTag, V : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, V)], keys: List[K] = List.empty[K]): List[(K, RDD[V])] = {

    val keysIn: List[K] = if (keys.isEmpty) rdd.map(_._1).distinct.collect.toList else keys

    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(rdd2: RDD[(K, V)], keys: List[K], output: List[(K, RDD[V])]): List[(K, RDD[V])] = {

        val currentKey :: keyxs = keys

        val filtered = rdd2.filter(_._1 == currentKey)
        val rest = rdd2.filter(_._1 != currentKey)

        val updatedOutput = (currentKey, filtered.map(_._2)) :: output

        if (keys.isEmpty) updatedOutput.reverse
        // Supposing rdd is cached, it is good to cache rest or does it will generate many smallest cached version of rdd which risk to overload ram ?
        else go(rest, keyxs, updatedOutput)

    }

    go(rdd, keysIn, List.empty[(K, RDD[V])])

}
```

Comment: hard to follow.

Comment: May I ask, why do you want this data structure?

Comment: I need to accumulate data with same key in order to apply function of kind `f: Collection[V] => Output`, and i m not sure than an aggregate/groupByKey will do the job. From what i know aggregate/groupByKey gather data with same Key on the same partition, but if there is too many data on a partition, it would failed i presume, that's why i'm filtering recursively the RDD.

Comment: @KyBe and how would having different RDDs avoid the failure due excessive memory usages if you need all the values on a local collection? The ide is that you must refactor your algorithm for not needing all the values at once and use `reduceByKey`.

Comment: I do not want reduceByKey because what i need is accumulate values into a `Collection[V]` not reduce them into a `V`.

Comment: @KyBe that is what `aggregateByKey` will do. If that can blow your memory then this approach will also do it.